# Can the Leidenfrost effect mitigate thermal effects of a nuclear blast?

Tags: thermodynamics, nuclear-physics, explosions

I'm just spit-balling ideas for a video game scenario. I'm curious whether an above-ground structure with active insulation layers could withstand being in the blast radius of a strike capable of taking out a sizable metro area.

Say we're given 5 minutes warning and expensive equipment in multiple armored buildings across a 20 x 20 mile region. Each building having up to 10 layers of alternating temperature regions, temporarily sustained by internal generators during the strike. From my perspective it would still come down to whether or not the building could survive the shock waves structurally but would this be enough to prevent the devastating temperatures from reaching residents within?

Comment: while i can see a correlation to engineering this is definitely a physics question which engineers would not be suited for. [re:the meta post](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/4536/), besides having only a very small consensus and many dissenters, this question does not fit into the reasons given in the meta post nor the suggested alternative QA sites. this question is about the nature of two physical phenomena, not the materials or construction needed to produce the solution. not off topic.